# Stack is Full Logical Error?

Tags: data-structures, stack

I am Learning Stack Data Structure and Unfortunately in my first code I am getting Stack is Full Run time error due to my less knowledge of Stack I am unable to Trace error in my written code please have a look.
Thanks

#include

```
using namespace std;

struct Stack
{

    int data[15];
    int top;
};


void init(Stack &s)
{
    s.top=-1;
}

bool isEmpty(Stack s)
{
    if(s.top == -1)

        return true;

    else
        return false;
}

bool isFull(Stack s)
{
    if(s.top > 14)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false ;
    }
}

void push ( Stack &s,int value)
{

    if(isFull(s) == true)
    {
        cout<<"Oooops Stack is Full :(\n";
    }
    else
    {
        s.top++;
        s.data[s.top]=value;
    }

}

int pop (Stack &s)
{
    int removedValue = s.data[s.top];
    s.data[s.top]=0;
    if(isEmpty(s)== true)
    {
        cout<<"Ohhh Stack is Empty\n";
    }
    else
    {
        s.top--;

        return removedValue;
    }

}

int top(Stack s)
{
    return s.top;
}
int main()
{
    Stack items;
    cout << "Hello Welcome to Stack!" << endl;
    push(items,1);
    cout<<pop(items)<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What language is this? C++? C#?

Answer (score 0):

ok folks here is the error..

i declared a new stack named Stack in main but didnot initialize it using

`void init(Stack &s)
{
    s.top=-1;
}`

so here is the answer by initializing stack in main()

```
Stack items;
init(items);
```